# Named Entity Recognition Python

Tags: python, nlp, entity, named

What I want to do: Extract all the occurrences of n consecutive words that all begin with a capital letter.

```
Input: ("Does John Doe eat pizza in New York?", 2)
Output: [("Does", "John"),("John", "Doe")("New","York")]

Input: ("Does John Doe eat pizza in New York?", 3)
Output: [("Does", "John","Doe")]
```

Here is what I have come up with so far:

```
# create text file
fw = open("ngram.txt", "w")
fw.write ("Does John Doe eat pizza in New York?")
fw.close()

def UpperCaseNGrams (file,n):
    fr = open (file, "r")
    text = fr.read().split()

    ngramlist = [text[word:word+n] for word in range(len(text)-(n-1)) if word[0].isupper() if word+n[0].isupper()]  
    return ngramlist

print (UpperCaseNGrams("ngram.txt",2))
```

I get the following error:
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

What do I have to change in order for it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `word+n[0].isupper()`, both `word` and `n` are of type `int` and therefore can not be indexed using `[]`, i.e. integers are not subscriptable.

I think that your intention is to check that the nth word past the current one starts with a capital, however, that would be done with `text[word+n][0]`. Regardless, I don't think that your method is going to work for values of `n` other than 2, e.g. if `n` were 3 you would need to check that all words between the current one and the nth word past the current one are capitalised.

The easiest fix is to use `all()` to check that each sublist of words begin with a capital:

```
ngramlist = [text[word:word+n] for word in range(len(text)-(n-1))
                 if all(s[0].isupper() for s in text[word:word+n])]
```

If you want something a bit faster you could do something like this to group runs of capitalised words together:

```
from itertools import groupby

text = 'Does John Doe eat pizza in New York?'.split()
caps_words = [list(v) for g,v in groupby(text, key=lambda x: x[0].isupper()) if g]
print(caps_words)
```

This would output

```
[['Does', 'John', 'Doe'], ['New', 'York?']]
```

Now you need to extract sublists of length `n` from each run:

```
ngrams = []
n = 2
for run in caps_words:
    ngrams.extend(run[i:i+n] for i in range(len(run)-(n-1)))
```

which results in `ngrams`:

```
[['Does', 'John'], ['John', 'Doe'], ['New', 'York?']]
```

and for `n` = 3:

```
[['Does', 'John', 'Doe']]
```

Putting that all together (and turning the ngram accumulator into a list comprehension) results in a function like this:

```
from itertools import groupby

def upper_case_ngrams(words, n):
    caps_words = [list(v) for g,v in groupby(words, key=lambda x: x[0].isupper()) if g]
    return [tuple(run[i:i+n]) for run in caps_words
                for i in range(len(run)-(n-1))]

text = 'Does John Doe eat pizza in New York?'.split()
for n in range(1, 5):
   print(upper_case_ngrams(text, n))
```

**Output**

```
[('Does',), ('John',), ('Doe',), ('New',), ('York?',)]
[('Does', 'John'), ('John', 'Doe'), ('New', 'York?')]
[('Does', 'John', 'Doe')]
[]
```

Comment: Wow thanks for your effort. :) I will need some time to work through it.

Comment: Possibly something like this too: https://gist.github.com/alvations/73bce71acf229265bc08